# Impossible to test whether Button.click event is null

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I need to test whether my `button.Click` event is null or not. Here is the event in c#:

```
button.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(Lancement_Formualire_Event);
```

I tested with

```
(button.Click == null)
```

but the compiler refuses to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly are you trying to do? Are you testing if the button has an event handler for the `Click` event?

Answer (score 5):

> I tested with (bouton.Click == null) but the compiler refuses to do so.

Indeed. That's not allowed by the abstraction of events. All an event allows you to do is subscribe to it, or unsubscribe from it. You shouldn't care about other subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

You might accomplish what you need if you extend the `Button` class with an empty "wrapper", which in turn would implement its own `Click` event and just relay it to `Button.Click`.

The difference is, that your custom "wrapper" would have at its disposal the very `event` object, which can be checked like you want to.

It's similar to what is commonly done when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and should answer your need.